# SQL IN Statement using like syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to do something like this i.e., use wild card characters in the in clause:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE keywords IN ('%test%', '%testing%')
```

This is not supported in SQL Server.... Is there some other way to achieve it...

Looking for something other than:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE keywords like '%test%' or keywords like '%testing%' or.....
```

Comment: I presume your actual usage is more complex, but in the example you gave you only need LIKE '%test%' since anything that matches '%testing%' also matches '%test%'.  Also, if you have control over your database structure, you'd be better off normalizing the storage of keywords.

Comment: @larry lustig: I was just giving a toy example... I want to do something little complex.. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, only other way I can think of is joining in to a temp table but then you have to eliminate duplicate rows.

This query of yours is horribly inefficient as it will unconditionally table scan. Perhaps you should look at separating the keywords or introducing a full text index.

If you would like to look into doing full text searches, then I would recommend looking into some of the heavy weights out there like sphinx or lucene when you evaluate the Sql Server full-text solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
  mytable M
  JOIN
  (
  SELECT '%test%' AS pattern
  UNION ALL SELECT '%testing%'
  ...
  ) foo ON M.keywords LIKE foo.Pattern
```

Could be a CTE or temp table too

Comment: @OMG Ponies: absolutely. Doh!

Comment: note on performance, best case (1 keyword) this will be as fast as the original. Worst case it will be a few times slower depending on row width due to the `distinct`

Comment: @Sam Saffron: it will be poor whichever way without proper text search

Answer (score 2):

> This is not supported in MS SQL.... Is
>   there some other way to achieve it?

Yes, [Full Text Search.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) At least [for prefix wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295266/sql-server-fulltext-search-for-book).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular Expression** to do this.
In one Regular Expression you can define as many pattern as you want in one expression.

There are lot's of article about Regular Expression Matching in MS SQL SERVER.
I used **RLIKE** in **MySQL** to do Regular Expression Matching.

I also attached [link1](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) & [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)   for MS SQL SERVER Regular Expression Matching.