# Sql Server Full-Text Search with wild card suffix using Entity Framework 6 Interceptor

Tags: entity-framework-6, full-text-search, wildcard

http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch

This example works fine for full word searches but does not talk about how to implement wild card suffix.

For example, I can do the following in SQL and get results for "bill" or "billy" using '*' in the end. How do I add that to my Interceptor?

`select * from dbo.messagethread a
where contains(Text, '"bil*"')`

If you look at that example code in that link above, I was thinking if something like this (below) is possible, but obviously that does not work as it is getting added to the parameter name not the value.

`string.Format(@"contains([$1].[$2], @{0} *)", parameter.ParameterName));`

There are questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585607/sql-server-full-text-search-is-it-possible-to-search-in-the-middle-of-a-word) which talk about wildcards in full-text in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for this line in the example link provided in the question.

`parameter.Value = value;`

Then, to do prefix match, just add this line below that.

`value = $"\"{value}*\""; // prefix match`

We're basically changing the value of the parameter to have the * in it inside double quotes.
Now if you search for "bil", you get results for "bill"/"billy" and so on.