# Check if a column contains text using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which is called `studentID`, but I have *millions* of records and somehow the application has input some *arbitrary text* in the column.

How do I search:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STUDENTS
 WHERE STUDENTID CONTAINS TEXT
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295266/full-text-catalog-index-search-for-book). I assume that if you use **CONTAINS**, you are using Full text catalog.

Comment: Are you looking for "Text" or are you looking for any non-numeric text? It makes a difference to the question you're asking.

Comment: Other link that may be useful [SQL Server LIKE vs CONTAINS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510685/1563878).

Comment: When using TEXT as raw SQL, make sure it's escaped, preferably using prepared statements.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Leaving database modeling issues aside. 
I think you can try

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE ISNUMERIC(STUDENTID) = 0
```

But `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 for any value that seems numeric including things like `-1.0e5`

If you want to exclude digit-only studentids, try something like

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC returns 1/0, would have to be `WHERE ISNUMERIC(STUDENTID) <> 1`

Answer (score 28):

Just try below script:

Below code works only if studentid column datatype is varchar

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID like '%Searchstring%'
```

Answer (score 13):

Try `LIKE` construction, e.g. (assuming `StudentId` is of type `Char`, `VarChar` etc.)

```
  select * 
    from Students
   where StudentId like '%' || TEXT || '%' -- <- TEXT - text to contain
```

Comment: SqlServer uses a `+` as string concat operator, not a `||`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190301.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SElECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE LEN(CAST(STUDENTID AS VARCHAR)) > 0
```

With this you get the rows where STUDENTID contains text

Answer (score 2):

riffing from bgs, please upvote them first.
I just wanted to expand on it

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID == 'Searchstring'
```

Will ONLY find Searchstring

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID like '%Searchstring%'
```

will find
1 Searchstring 1
2 Searchstring 2
3Searchstring3
etc Searchstring etc

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID like 'Searchstring%'
```

will find
Searchstring 1
Searchstring 2
SearchstringEtc
Will not find
1 Searchstring 1
or any prefixes at all

In this case % is used kinda the same as the same as the * wildcard, just for strings in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose STUDENTID contains some characters or numbers that you already know i.e. 'searchstring' then below query will work for you.

You could try this:

```
select * from STUDENTS where CHARINDEX('searchstring',STUDENTID)>0
```

I think this one is the fastest and easiest one.